# self.tableview reloadData causing crash in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm getting this crash when selecting a row: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)',

I moved the data out of the viewWillAppear because we though it was causing a crash. I now have it loading on ViewDidLoad.

However if the [self.tableview reloadData]; is on, I get this crash.

Ideas?

```
  -(void) loadData3;{

    MyAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.tableDataSource3 = [AppDelegate.data3 objectForKey:@"Rows"];
NSLog(@"AppDelegate.data3 : %@",AppDelegate.data3 );
NSLog(@"self.tableDataSource3 : %@",self.tableDataSource3 );

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    [self loadData3];
    if(CurrentLevel3 == 0) {
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Families I Follow";
}
else 
    self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle3;  
}
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear: animated];
            [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? Post the code in that section.

Comment: Not sure if this was just a typo, but [self.tableview reloadData] should be [self.tableView reloadData].  Capital V in tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, you are changing the Array that loads the UITableView while it is being displayed, so when you click on a Row the row no longer exists in the Array. Therefore, the out of bounds error on the Array.

Comment: that makes sense. I thought if I had the getdata within the viewWillAppear that it would get it after an update. Now to figure out where to put it.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use the same data Array to populate a parent and child UITableViews. This is incorrect. Either create a new data Array, or make a copy of the current Array.

Comment: It's a basic drill down NSDictionary, If you take out the reload, everything works and drills down. I don't need a new one, just a refreshed one with the new data that was just downloaded and saved to the phone. Thanks for your time one this, I appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure I or any one else can help without seeing e code. If you want to zip it and put it somewhere I can take a look.

Comment: I am trying the NSURLconnection process.

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Moving `reloadData` to `viewDidAppear` solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since its happening while selecting a row, the error is most likely in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method(s). Nothing seems intrinsically wrong with the `viewWillAppear:` code fragment that you've posted.